# android creating text view dynamically

Tags: android

I'm new to android. just playing with the basic things. here's my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
    // Get the message from the intent
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String status = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(status);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    linearLayout.addView(textView);
}
```

XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff99ccff"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
</LinearLayout>
```

when i run this on my phone it says, "unfortunately, the app has stopped"

Comment: this part of your code is wrong String status = intent.getStringExtra(MyActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE); show the Logcat please

Answer (score 3):

Change the order like

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
```

You must `setContentView(...)` first and then initialize your `Views`.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Can you please tell me what's the difference between the two?

Comment: @BenZRayne Read my answer carefully. You must set content View first. (Window) and then you initialized views from that.

Answer (score 1):

You can add text view dynamically in other way also :

1. Create method inside your activity :

   ```
   private TextView getCustomTextView(Context context, String tvValue, String tvHint) {

       TextView textView = new TextView(context);
       textView.setText("" + tvValue);
       textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
       textView.setTextSize(20);

       // to set font family
       Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
               "fonts/epimodem.ttf");
       textView.setTypeface(face);

       textView.setHint(tvHint+""); // static 
       textView.setHint(context.getString(R.string.text_hint)); // from string file
       textView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
       return textView;

   }
   ```
2. Add text view in linearlayout.

   `linearLayout.addView(getCustomTextView(this, "text value in string", "hint value in string"));`
3. You can more then one text view using same code.