# How do I dynamically add TextViews to my layout based on the content of a JSON file?

Tags: android, json, android-layout, kotlin

I'm new to android development. I have a JSON File that contains a number of objects, how do I add a new TextView to my ScrollView for every object in the JSON file? Each TextView would store the data contained in the JSON Object. The only way I know at the moment to add Views to a Layout is by defining them in the activity layout XML file, But that doesn't allow for me to automatically generate them, I have to create them all by hand and define them manually.

Thanks

EDIT: The linked duplicate didn't have any answers, however an answer has been provided here.

Comment: Try to use `listView` or `RecyclerView`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android creating text view dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29387403/android-creating-text-view-dynamically)

Comment: You have to use xml to define view. One thing you can do is add views as per the number of objects in your json(have their visibility set to invisible or gone) and for each object you check validity and then make that view visible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Lewiky, Here is .java file code for adding TextView to a ScrollView dynamically. You can replace the loop through according to your json objects length. Also posting the xml layout file code for your reference

```
public class Scrollview extends AppCompatActivity {
    ScrollView scrollview;
    LinearLayout linearLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrollview);


        scrollview = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
        linearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.scrllinear);
        TextView textView;

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText("I=" + i);
            linearLayout.addView(textView, lp);
        }

    }

}
```

XML code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relative"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrllinear"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps, 
Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

I Supposing that you have a `activity_layout.xml` and `SomeActivity` and both have a relation wihch `setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)` method, called in overridden method `onCreate`, like this:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_layout)
}
```

Now, you need finder some `ViewGroup` like: `LinearLayout`, `ListView` (better). Using method `findViewById(R.id.some_group_view)` and cast with the same class.

With instanced variables (supposing you use `ListView`) map you Json object and extract the needed information in Iterator object and pass data in you `ArrayAdapter`.

See Android developer guides for make application. They have a really useful documentation.

[Android developer Main page](https://developer.android.com/index.html)
[Android developer Guides](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)
[Android developer ListView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html)